# git Update failed

Tags: git, gitlab

```
08:01 AM    Update failed
                cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/IA-1255|IA-1222|IA-1224|IA-1223.voiceItem': Unable to create 'C:/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/igap/.git/refs/remotes/origin/IA-1255|IA-1222|IA-1224|IA-1223.voiceItem.lock': Invalid argument
                From **************
                ! deb55c3e8..9c75fbc5f  IA-1255|IA-1222|IA-1224|IA-1223.voiceItem -> origin/IA-1255|IA-1222|IA-1224|IA-1223.voiceItem  (unable to update local ref)
```

I get this error when I try to get a new update from Brunch Beta, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is simple: the branch name `IA-1255|IA-1222|IA-1224|IA-1223.voiceItem` is simply not allowed on Windows.  Rename the branch.

(It should be allowed; that it's not is a very long-standing Git issue that has been in Git since the very first version.  But it's *not* allowed, so that's the end of it for now.)